# The model group is exported to GLB format. After threejs is imported, can I add materials to the models in the model group separately

Tags: javascript, three.js

For example, the name of the model group I exported is C. There are two models A and B in model group C. After exporting GLB file with blender, are there labels containing models A and B in the file? What code do I need to use to get model A in model group C and give a material to A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally can query 3D objects by using [Object3D.getObjectByName()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName). In context of `glTF`, the code should look like so:

```js
const object = gltf.scene.getObjectByName( 'name' );
```